# Is there a safe CKEditor output viewer?

Tags: ckeditor

As far as I understand CKEditor just outputs HTML, you are supposed to validate that HTML, and output it as an HTML, too many XSS issues to consider in my opinion.

Is there a CKEditor Output Viewer, that will take that HTML as input and view it safely.

So let's say a malicious party sent bunch of script tags instead of CKEditor output, without any tampering on the server side, the output will go to client side, and this clever "Viewer" will strip malicious script tags and view that HTML's output.

I've searched but couldn't come up with anything, is there something like this?

Comment: I'd recommend server side tampering in all cases, meaning don't strip malicious tags in the Viewer but rather in the Server. CKE has pretty good content filtering as well but of course that is not enough. For secure sites, a server side whitelist based check would be best.

Comment: logical, I decided not to add rich editing capabilities after all, too much thinking, worrying in my opinion